# Check if page works using SSL in PHP

Tags: php, http, ssl

I need to check if a page works using SSL connection. I know how to check `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'`. Is this a good way of doing it, or should I use other logic? 
Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS']` *may* contain values other than `'on'` or it may not be set at all. [The manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) it'll be set to a "non empty" value if SSL is used, but on IIS it may be set to `'off'`. So, use:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
    // I feel insecure...
} else {
    // SSL, yay!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On checking the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) I figured that `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off"` should be enough to detect if you are using `https://`, not just `$_SERVER['HTTPS"] == "on"`.

Apparently using ISAPI with IIS the value is, confusingly, set to `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, and so an `empty()` or `isset()` check alone with not suffice.